# SOAP request seems not work

Tags: android, soap

I'm trying to make call on a .NET webservice from Android.
These are my variables:

```
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.greenparkvieste.it/";
private final String URL = "http://nursexpress.hellonetlab.it/service.asmx?op=UserLogin";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.greenparkvieste.it/UserLogin";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "UserLogin";
private String risposta = "";
```

This is my method executed in doInBackground in an AsyncTask:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

request.addProperty("userName", "Ale");
request.addProperty("password", "ciaociao");

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.encodingStyle = "utf-8";
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

//Create HTTP call object
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

try {
    //Invole web service
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    //Get the response
    SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
    //Assign it to fahren static variable
    risposta = response.toString();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When I start the application it gives me this error:
[image]

What is wrong?

Comment: I solved uploading ksoap2 library!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have test your web service in SoupUI tool( web service test tool)

[SoupUI download from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/)

there problem in web service

this is exception while create in SoupUI tool

**Error loading [http://nursexpress.hellonetlab.it/service.asmx?op=UserLogin]: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected character encountered: 'v**